# R help is not updated in Eclipse after R CMD install

Tags: eclipse, r, statet

I am developing a R package in Eclipse. Although I am new to this environment, it's been great.

But one problem I am facing is that after running R CMD install after check and build in Eclipse, if I type in R console of Eclipse,

```
library(mypackagename)
?mypackagename
```

Eclipse still displays old help. I've already tried restarting, rebooting, and so on in vain.  If I run R in windows, it displays correct help for the package. I wonder what is going on.

I suspect Eclipse has its own cache for R help but can't find how to delete it.

**Update** As seen in @JimM's answer, you should select following to update R help.

`"R console View menu" -> R environment -> Index completely`

This will take 2-3 mins but I found there is no other way to update R help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the StatET plug-in, there's a couple of ways to update the R environment.

First, To update the R environment manually, in the Console window in the StatET perspective, there's a downward facing triangle in the top right corner.  If you click and hold the triangle, there is the option under the R environment to either "Index completely" or "Index changes".  If you choose to "Index completely", it will rebuild the entire R Index/Help cache.

Alternatively, under Preferences > StatET > Run/Debug > R Environments, there's an option to update the R Environment index to "Check and Update Automatically".

Comment: Selecting `Index completely` did the trick! "Check and Update Automatically" was checked in my Eclipse but somehow it was missing my package. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting frustrated by this too. Only in the StatET plugin in Eclipse was my package's online help not updating; from Rconsole or Rgui it was. I found that a good way of ensuring that the help automatically updates when you reload a package is to bump up the version number in your DESCRIPTION file. As soon as you drop in the updated package the R environment is automatically updated but unfortunately StatET seems to get confused w.r.t. the R-help and so you still need to restart the R console in Eclipse.